# In Java is there a preferred method of casting an object?

Tags: java, casting, reference

I have a superclass person with a subclass student. I have made a student object of type person, and wanted to call a student specific method which does not exist in the person type. I have two methods below that can do this, and I was curious to know is one method superior to the other, or do they both achieve the same outcome?

```
    Person newStudent = new Student("Scott", 22, "B22334952");

    //method1: make a reference of newStudent and cast to Student
    Student studentRef = (Student) newStudent;
    System.out.println(studentRef.getUserId());

    //method2: cast newStudent, but don't create a reference
    System.out.println(((Student) student2).getUserId());
```

Comment: Both are fine. Use the one that makes you feel comfortable. If I were to use `studentRef` several times, I would use method 1, if I would use it in a single LoC then method 2.

Comment: Hopefully it's clear they produce the same outcome. Which is preferable depends entirely on your complete usecase. Why don't people have a user ID, though? That seems fairly universal. Doing it this way requires checking the type first; without knowing precisely what you're doing it's hard to say if this is a bad design or not.

Comment: The trick is to avoid having to cast it in the first place. But yes both ways are equally good here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They'll both have the same outcome.

Create a variable to store the result of the cast if you need to reuse the cast reference.

When you perform a cast, you are setting yourself up for `ClassCastException`, so always be mindful. You can always check the type before you attempt a cast

```
if (newStudent instanceof Student) {
    Student studentRef = (Student) newStudent;
}
```

Comment: +1 for correctness.  But I'd also recommend not writing code like this.

Comment: @AmirAfghani why not? In fact, it's a matter of style and readability. In fact, I find this kind of specific downcasting a problem at all...

Comment: @AmirAfghani Do you mean without casting or the second option?

Comment: @AmirAfghani I'm currently learning inheritance so this is more of a thought experiment to get an understanding of how all this Java business works.

Comment: I mean not casting unless it's unavoidable

Comment: @ScottIrvine - Thats great that you are learning this stuff.  Thats sort of what I thought was going on, and thats why I encouraged Sotirios to provide the admonishment.

Answer (score 1):

Both are similar.

Use the second one if you don't want to use that information anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use whichever you prefer, this is a meaningless micro-optimization and will result in equivalent byte code. You could also use [`Class.cast(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) like

```
System.out.println(Student.class.cast(newStudent).getUserId());
```

Answer (score 1):

Best of all, **don't cast**.  Casting means your code is making assumptions that cannot be verified at compile time, and that's a recipe for trouble.  Declare variable types that capture the full requirements and expectations of their values, and rely only on those declared types.

So,

```
// Declare a Student because a plain Person won't do
Student newStudent = new Student("Scott", 22, "B22334952");

System.out.println(newStudent.getUserId());
```